# how do I replace dynamic variables which are unknown dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a .js file which has config structure something like this.

```
genGetLocations:{
   data_url:'restaurants/{var1}/tables/{var2},
}
```

THis is one example. Some might have config that has data_url which has more than two dynamic variables. Then in .vue file, after getting the data_url, i will have two ids which have to be replaced into var1 and var2 so that I will have the final rest api url to make the request to.

**Problem**: I don't know how many variables each data_url is going to have and where they are going to be placed in data_url. So, in .vue files, when I will have the ids, i want to replace them in data_url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is looking for every {} in your URL. So it could be `{var1}`, `{string2}` or so.

Try this:

```js
var info = {"genGetLocations":{
   "data_url" : "restaurants/{var1}/tables/{var2}"
}};

var ids = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
var regexp = /\{.*?\}/g;
var results = info.genGetLocations.data_url.match(regexp);
var replacedString = info.genGetLocations.data_url;
results.forEach(function(result, index) {
  replacedString = replacedString.replace(new RegExp(result,"g"), ids[index]); 
});

console.log(replacedString);
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, could you change this so that it's not mandatory to use variables that have numbers in it? such as var1 and var2 and instead (ffff, varasd, anything).

Comment: okay, done. now the numbers don't play a role anymore. If this answer was helpful, please mark it as accepted :-)

Comment: I would guess this is _probably_ not what @NikaKurashvili really wants. In particular, they probably want `"restaurants/{foo}/tables/{bar}"` to produce a different result than `"restaurants/{bar}/tables/{foo}"`. With your edited code, both will be exactly the same (but `"restaurants/{foo}/tables/{foo}"` will be different, which is also kind of weird).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on whether your IDs are in an array or an object, you could do one of the following:

```js
const data = 'restaurants/{var1}/tables/{var2}';
const idsArray = [101, 102];

console.log(
  data.replace(/\{var(\d+)\}/g, (substr, idx) => idsArray[parseInt(idx) - 1])
);
```

```js
const data = 'restaurants/{var1}/tables/{var2}';
const idsObj = {
  var1: 101,
  var2: 102
};

console.log(
  data.replace(/\{(var\d+)\}/g, (substr, key) => idsObj[key])
);
```

If you want the keys to be arbitrary:

```js
const data = 'restaurants/{foo}/tables/{bar}';
const idsObj = {
  foo: 101,
  bar: 102
};

console.log(
  data.replace(/\{(.*?)\}/g, (substr, key) => idsObj[key])
);
```

Comment: Looks nice. what if I don't know what those names will be ? such as I may not know they are called 'var1' and 'var2'. Is it still possible?

Comment: @NikaKurashvili: Yes, the last code snippet above (with the example keys `foo` and `bar`) should work. At least assuming that your code will _eventually_ know at runtime what key each value should replace. If you won't even know that, you'll have a bigger issue.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this

```js
String.prototype.formatUnicorn = String.prototype.formatUnicorn || function () {
     var e = this.toString();
     if (!arguments.length)
      return e;
     var t = typeof arguments[0],
     n = "string" == t || "number" == t ? Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) : arguments[0];
     for (var i in n)
      e = e.replace(new RegExp("\\{" + i + "\\}", "gi"), n[i]);
     return e
    }
    
    /** Lets Assume your Code 
    genGetLocations:{
   data_url:'restaurants/{var1}/tables/{var2},
}**/
console.log('restaurants/{var1}/tables/{var2}'.formatUnicorn({'var1':'test1','var2':'test2'}))
```

Comment: [That code looks familiar.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207128/what-is-formatunicorn-for-strings) It's also not very good code, despite having been written by some mythical Stack Exchange developer back in the mists of time. In particular, it's a lot less efficient than [amitic's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57865883), breaks if any of the keys contain any characters that have a special meaning in a regexp, and can also behave in unexpected ways if any of the replacement strings themselves contain `{placeholders}`.